# Is it possible to use PHP to code an Amazon Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to use other languages aside from Node.js, Python, Java, and C# with lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Natively AWS Lambda supports only following languages

1. Java 8
2. C#
3. Edge Node.js 4.3
4. Node,js 4.3
5. Node.js 6.10
6. Python 2.7
7. Python 3.6

However, if you want to use PHP, you can still do that with a bit of a workaround as outlined in the blog [Scripting Languages for AWS Lambda: Running PHP, Ruby, and Go](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will try it out. Have you tried coding with php on lambda before?

Answer (score 0):

you need to upload php binaries (php executable, .so files etc) and ini files as part of your lambda deployment.
one good option for doing this is https://serverless.com/
and then you need something to manage the execution of the php functions.
check this out: https://github.com/niron1/serverless-php-lambda
(I'm the author)